# Encode URL parameter values for sensitive content?

Tags: security, url, url-parameters

For those of you who often build web applications will know that at some point you will need some URL parameters sent.

The values of these parameters might even be sensitive and can be abused.

For instance, User 1 wants to vew User 2 so a URL might be

```
http://www.example.com/User/2
```

This works fine and it is easy to read the URL parameter in the code.

However this leads to a problem: If User 1 does not have access to User 2 then User 1 would easily be able to type this URL into his browser. Normally when you want to avoid access you use some form of access control (like ACL), however my question is in cases where the data is sensitive, is it better to make the URL string into an encoded string aswell?

A great example is LinkedIn. Here is a URL with what I think is an encoded parameter:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/hp/?dnr=wxTvRoX8KGA5n3H4yxFpQfGTcdpfl3PW5Ab5
```

Is there any rule for when you want to encode or not? And should you always use encoded strings?

Comment: I think the rule should be based on the question: it's private or public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you don't want to put sensitive material into an URL. URLs have the tendency of being bookmarked, emailed, logged, etc... All things that make an URL not very private. Encoding the sensitive information is *slightly* better than not encoding it as the encoded information won't be accidentally viewed by someone. They'll have to intentionally decode before they can view it.

There are reasons beyond security for encoding URL parameters. A common example is to store a small binary data structure in the URL parameter such as page referrer information or a binary key into a table. My assumption is that the LinkedIn `dnr` parameter is encoded but not sensitive.